# Load multiple models from single controller

Tags: php, laravel

need help laravel. 
I have 2 model in different folder

1. app\User
2. app\model\Role

there is no problem when i used at **UsersController** -> call *app\User*, or **RolesController** -> call *app\model\Role*

but, when i used both models on **UsersController** , the *app\model\Role* didnt work

==================== UsersController ======================

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use app\User;
use app\model\Role as Role;
use DataTables;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request){
        $data['title_page'] = 'User';
        $data['roles']  = Role::all(); // this line show error 
        return view('admin/user', $data);
    }
}
```

======================== app\model\Role ===================

```
namespace App\model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['id','name'];

    protected $tables = 'roles';

    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','role');
    }
}
```

======================== app\User =======================

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = "users";

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','role', 'status'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function roles(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\model\Role','id');
    }


}
```

Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Class 'app\model\Role' not found

Comment: Can you share here User model as well ?

Comment: i have edit my question, add existing User model

Comment: Have you tried:  composer dump-autoload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with capital 'A' on 'App'. Some systems are case sensitive. So `use App\Model\Role` depending on your folder name for model.  IE if your `model` folder is lower case, match it in the `use` statement.

Also, you don't need the as keyword here unless there are conflicts - you may be fine with just `use App\Model\Role` without the `as Role`.

One more item, make sure the **Role** class is actually in the model folder and that your namespace is at the top of the php file correctly referencing the App\Model namespace.  So in your **Role** class make sure the caps match your use call -

```
<?php

namespace App\Model
```

Comment: The code is weird, that's sure. But I think that's not the reason actually. He is also used models from different directories as well. May they just exists some autoload classes, which he must to dump.. hmm

Comment: My pleasure.  Its the matching between namespace caps and use calls that is the gotcha usually :)

Comment: ;) I just wondering from where you learned the code styling.. why not to write beautiful code and get success