# Class 'Seeder' not found

Tags: laravel

I've created migrations and migrated them to the database. Now ready to create seeders, but `php artisan db:seed` gives this error `Class 'Seeder' not found`.

How do I create a seeder class and where is it stored?

I'm following this tutorial https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-guide-to-using-eloquent-orm-in-laravel and am at the point where we 'Seeding a Database with Relationships'.

Here is my `DatabaseSeeder.php`

```
// app/database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php
<?php

use App\Bear;
use App\Tree;
use App\Fish;
use App\Picnic;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{

    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Eloquent::unguard();

        // call our class and run our seeds
        $this->call('BearAppSeeder');
        $this->command->info('Bear app seeds finished.'); // show information in the command line after everything is run
    }
}

// our own seeder class
// usually this would be its own file
class BearAppSeeder extends Seeder
{

    public function run()
    {

        // clear our database ------------------------------------------
        DB::table('bears')->delete();
        DB::table('fish')->delete();
        DB::table('picnics')->delete();
        DB::table('trees')->delete();
        DB::table('bears_picnics')->delete();

        // seed our bears table -----------------------
        // we'll create three different bears

        // bear 1 is named Lawly. She is extremely dangerous. Especially when hungry.
        $bearLawly = Bear::create(array(
            'name'         => 'Lawly',
            'type'         => 'Grizzly',
            'danger_level' => 8
        ));

        // bear 2 is named Cerms. He has a loud growl but is pretty much harmless.
        $bearCerms = Bear::create(array(
            'name'         => 'Cerms',
            'type'         => 'Black',
            'danger_level' => 4
        ));

        // bear 3 is named Adobot. He is a polar bear. He drinks vodka.
        $bearAdobot = Bear::create(array(
            'name'         => 'Adobot',
            'type'         => 'Polar',
            'danger_level' => 3
        ));

        $this->command->info('The bears are alive!');

        // seed our fish table ------------------------
        // our fish wont have names... because theyre going to be eaten

        // we will use the variables we used to create the bears to get their id

        Fish::create(array(
            'weight'  => 5,
            'bear_id' => $bearLawly->id
        ));
        Fish::create(array(
            'weight'  => 12,
            'bear_id' => $bearCerms->id
        ));
        Fish::create(array(
            'weight'  => 4,
            'bear_id' => $bearAdobot->id
        ));

        $this->command->info('They are eating fish!');

        // seed our trees table ---------------------
        Tree::create(array(
            'type'    => 'Redwood',
            'age'     => 500,
            'bear_id' => $bearLawly->id
        ));
        Tree::create(array(
            'type'    => 'Oak',
            'age'     => 400,
            'bear_id' => $bearLawly->id
        ));

        $this->command->info('Climb bears! Be free!');

        // seed our picnics table ---------------------

        // we will create one picnic and apply all bears to this one picnic
        $picnicYellowstone = Picnic::create(array(
            'name'        => 'Yellowstone',
            'taste_level' => 6
        ));
        $picnicGrandCanyon = Picnic::create(array(
            'name'        => 'Grand Canyon',
            'taste_level' => 5
        ));

        // link our bears to picnics ---------------------
        // for our purposes we'll just add all bears to both picnics for our many to many relationship
        $bearLawly->picnics()->attach($picnicYellowstone->id);
        $bearLawly->picnics()->attach($picnicGrandCanyon->id);

        $bearCerms->picnics()->attach($picnicYellowstone->id);
        $bearCerms->picnics()->attach($picnicGrandCanyon->id);

        $bearAdobot->picnics()->attach($picnicYellowstone->id);
        $bearAdobot->picnics()->attach($picnicGrandCanyon->id);

        $this->command->info('They are terrorizing picnics!');
    }
}
```

After I got the error I tried to add a model called `Seeder.php` and added the following:

```
// app/models/seeder.php
<?php

class Seeder extends Seeder
{

    protected $fillable = [];
    protected $table = 'bear';
}
```

I've tried all the answers found on here, also `composer dump-autoload` but no joy.

Comment: Check your namespaces for consistency in caps against your `use` directives.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58244227/load-multiple-models-from-single-controller/58244407#58244407) for potentially the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure to import the Illuminate `Seeder` class which your class extends

```php
use App\Bear;
use App\Tree;
use App\Fish;
use App\Picnic;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
// Rest of code
```

At the top of your class

Comment: Ok thank you. I did that and now I get a new error ```Class 'Bear' not found```

Comment: Thank you, now I get this ```Class 'App\Bear' not found```

Comment: Updated now again

Comment: Still get the same ```Class 'App\Bear' not found``` error. Seems to be a FatalThrowableError on this line ```$bearLawly = Bear::create(array(``` I have updated my seeder code in my question above.

Comment: Could the problem be that my database table is names "bears" and not "bear"? Or perhaps in my ```public function run()```, instead of having ```DB::table('bears')->delete();``` I need to have the database name ```bears::table('bears')->delete();```?

Comment: I think you changed the default App namespace

Comment: Sorry, what does that mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200443/discussion-between-caddy-dz-and-php75dj).